# Javascript - extract specific numbers from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to extract specific numbers from a string but I'm not sure how to execute it.

The string is of the form:

```
center=43.571464,7.129565&zoom=12&size=480x225&markers=color:red%7Clabel:1%7C43.580293713725936,7.115145444335894&markers=color:red%7Clabel:2%7C43.56512073056565,7.121668576660113&sensor=false
```

The array I want is the marker coordinates near the end, specifically:

```
[43.580293713725936,7.115145444335894,43.56512073056565,7.121668576660113]
```

I thought I could pick these number out using their precision (15) but I don't know if that's best. I'm a hack when it comes to using regular expressions. Right now the best I've got is:

```
str.match(/[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+/g)
```

But that just gives me all of the numbers.

Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If your string is in `str` use this regex.

```
var coordinates = decodeURIComponent(str).match(/([\d.]{10,})/g);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CHfcT/

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the following regex

```
/\d+\.\d{7,}/g
```

This assumes that:

- The marker coordinates always have 7 or more numbers after the dot
- No other part of the string contains a similar pattern with more than 7 numbers after a dot

Example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4n7xp/)):

```
str.match(/\d+\.\d{7,}/g);
```

The reason I picked 7 was because the other numbers in the sample had 6, so that excludes them. If you know that the coordinates always have a fixed number of decimal places, then you could just use that specific number without the `,` like this:

```
/\s+\.\d{10}/g
```